# How does external electric field deflect a liquid stream?

Tags: electrostatics, atomic-physics

An external electric field can deflect a stream of water (made of polar molecules).

1- My understanding is that this is due to the fact that in presence of, say negative, external electric charge, water molecules orient themselves so that hydrogen atoms are closest to the negative charge, and since the distance between attracting charges (external negative charge and hydrogen atoms) is less than the distance between repulsing charges (external negative charge and oxygen atom), the net force will be toward external charge. is this correct?

2- Can a strong electric field have the same effect on a stream of a liquid made of non-polar molecules, say liquid methane, by pulling/pushing the electron cloud to one side of the molecule and temporarily make the molecule polar, and deflect the methane stream towards external electric charge?

Comment: can you please give a link describing the statement? experiment?

Comment: @annav https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhWQ-r1LYXY

Comment: I searched on google for "can an electric field polarize a non polar molecule" and three videos came up, but with people speaking english in a foreign way. also there are links to articles. they say yes to the second question.